# TRY and EXCEPT problem in a collatz conjecture

Tags: python, function, try-catch, except, collatz

[Here Is The Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mZWh.jpg)

[What I Get After The Execution Of The Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJscL.png)

Why is the programm printing number instead of using it as an argument in the collatz() function?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce the issue.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: You could use a `while True` block around the try/except and have a break after the call the `collatz`. The issue is your Python script is completing right after the print in the exception.